# How to measure speed from AWS regions to specific location (not mine)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, performance-testing

I'm looking for a way to pick the best AWS region to host a Proof of Concept installation for a potential customer in India.

For this, I'd like to try to ping the customer's web site (I verified that it's hosted in India, I assume by the customer itself since that's part of their business) from multiple AWS regions and see which one gives best results.

I found multiple tools which would allow me to run ping from my own browser to multiple AWS locations (e.g. https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest, http://www.cloudping.info/) but none which will allow me to ping between all AWS regions and a specific third party.

Does such a tool exist, or is my only option to run up an EC2 instance in each region and try to ping from it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the answers to [this very similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/466588/which-aws-zone-to-choose-if-website-traffic-will-be-from-india-only).

Keep in mind that not all regions have all AWS services available at this time, so make sure the region you pick has all the services that you plan to use. Also, Amazon has said that an India region [is in the works](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/in-the-works-aws-region-in-india/).

Comment: Thanks. The referenced question assumes that any region is an option. My current choices are limited (we have infrastructure of VPC's, AMI's and VPN's in only a few AWS regions), so I'd like to be able to measure things as they are today from specific AWS regions.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to just spin up a t2.micro instance in each region you want to compare, and perform the ping tests yourself.

Comment: yep, that sounds like it. I'm still hopeful to hear about a tool which already does this. After all - there are plenty of Pingdom-like tools all I need is something to do the same from all AWS regions.